# Implicit inheritance

Tags: node.js, typescript, inheritance, prototypal-inheritance

I'm using a library that extends the prototype of my classes. Although not important, in my case the library adds the `EventEmitter` prototype to my class, then it instantiates the class with an instance of an `EventEmitter`. I need to register for the events, but I'm having trouble getting `this` to play nice. The library was created before ES6 style inheritance via the `extends` keyword was introduced and I cannot change the library, thus I must rely on some kind of implicit inheritance in my classes.

Is it possible to implicitly inherit another type?

---

### Example code

```
import { EventEmitter } from 'events';
import { inherits } from 'util';

class Foo {
    constructor() {
        // Do something assuming
        // 'this' is an event emitter
    }
}

inherits(Foo, EventEmitter);

Foo.call(new EventEmitter());
```

---

### What I've tried

Explicit inheritance - expects call to `super`, the object is already an event emitter, I just want the types tied to my class.

```
class Foo extends EventEmitter {
    constructor() {
        this.on('event', ...)
    }
}
```

> [ts] Constructors for derived classes must contain a 'super' call.

---

Casting to `EventEmitter` before calling those methods.

```
class Foo {
    constructor() {
        const e = this as EventEmitter;
        e.on('event', ...)
    }
}
```

> [ts]
>   Type 'this' cannot be converted to type 'EventEmitter'.
>     Type 'Foo' is not comparable to type 'EventEmitter'.
>        Property 'addListener' is missing in type 'Foo'.

---

Casting to `any` then to `EventEmitter` works, but it feels like a hack. Requiring a cast everywhere is also not very elegant, I feel there is a more appropriate solution.

```
class Foo {
    constructor() {
        const e = this as any as EventEmitter;
        e.on('event', ...)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use class/interface declaration merging :

```
declare class EventEmitter{
  on(n:string):void
}
interface Foo extends EventEmitter { }
class Foo  {
    constructor() {
        this.on('event')
    }
}
```